# How to call function on ng-click on a <a> link with the ability to open in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an  element which goes something like this

```
<a ng-click="vm.openPage(page)">{{page.pageId}}</a>
```

There some validations in the `vm.openPage()` function which are necessary before it redirects to the page with this code

```
$state.go('page', {
   id: page.pageId
});
```

The problem is that I need that link to be able to be opened in a new tab with right-click but still run the function and the validation. Tried it with

```
ng-href={{vm.openPage(page)}}
```

but that runs the function at page load, and I can't have that because the link is a column in a table with 20 rows.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: don't use `ng-click`, use `ng-href` and `target="_blank"`. If you use ng-click, you can't use ctrl + click left and it's annoying.

Comment: Like i said if i use ng-href it runs the function automatically on page load for every row in the table, i need it to run only when i click on it or if i open it in new tab, and target="_blank" does not help with it.

Comment: use $state.href of the answer inside your ng-href. ng-href="$state.href(....)" then it should be good. It calculates the url, and doesn't redirect you directly, only if clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

use the following :

In your html :

```
 <a ng-href="{{(test() && url && !loading)||'#'}}">click here</a>
```

in your JS :

```
var url = "http://www.google.com";
$scope.test = function () {

     if(  $scope.pass =="pass") { // your condition
        return true;
     }
     else {
       return false;
     }

   };
```

make sure that while loading your page , the condition is false if it is true , set add loading status flag to your load function , and use it in your link

sample example in the following jsFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/h3vadqp9/)

Comment: That is ok if i want it to open always in a new tab when it enters the function, but i need it to be able to open in the same tab on just left click, and to open it in new tab if i want to right click and open in new tab.